# Is it possible to predict the weather like John Locke?

Tags: weather, climate-science

In series 1 of the TV show Lost, the character John Locke seems to be able to predict the weather preternaturally well; he says, during a monsoon, that the rain will stop in a minute, and lo and behold. Granted, he's in communion with a magical Island that probably bends a large number of the laws of physics, but it raises the question; can you, just by studying the atmosphere, predict the weather to a significant degree? If so, how far ahead could you guess with a reasonable accuracy rate what is going to happen? In particular, I mean without any specialist instruments or tools; just through expert observation.

Comment: Without measuring tools and many instruments (including powerfull computers for simulation), I believe that the best it's possible to sistematically do is to say if it's going to rain or not in the next few hours

Comment: I disagree. You will find that if you say "the weather tomorrow will be similar to what it is today", you will be right more times than you are wrong. Bear that in mind when you hear a claim about a high forecasting accuracy!

Comment: 30 days: http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/public/weather/forecast

Comment: yes up to a point (some say 4 days), then the [butterfly effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect) is big :)